# iPad won't let me update apps after update to iOS 14

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

Since updating iPads to iOS 14 I am not able to update apps. After hitting update I am asked for password which I do fill correctly. After about ten seconds the password dialogue appears again, and again, and again.

I do remember on both iPads Apple tried to force me into two factor authentication which I absolutely do not want. I have clicked on *Later* as there was no other option for opting out.

What can I do to be able to update the apps? Of course apart of setting up two factor authentication?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you do not want 2-factor authentication? - In 2020 that should be treated as a necessity to secure an account.

Comment: I would login to https://appleid.apple.com/ to see if Apple has some kind of message for your account, or if it has been disabled or similar.

Comment: @jksoegaard thank you, will have a look. Yeah, when Apple have two factor authentication in automated way which doesn't waste my time, I will be keen to use it.

Comment: The point of 2-factor authentication is that it is not automated. Automating it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @jksoegaard sure, sure. Let's focus on why I can't update my apps just because I have updated system on my iPads, I take it as pretty bad Apple fail.

Comment: I get that you think your problems are Apple's fault. It really doesn't help you getting it fixed though. If you want my help getting it fixed, I have given you my suggestion, as I think that is the best way to proceed to get your apps updating.

Comment: What happens if you sign out of iCloud (at the top of the Settings app) and then try to sign back in? If it still locks you out then it is likely Apple saying that you need to use 2FA, and you'll need to sign in like @jksoegaard suggests. Yah, I get that 2FA is annoying, but it is even *more* annoying to have your account hijacked.

Comment: @jksoegaard I do not think it is Apple fail. It is Apple fail for fact. If you really need to know how to do automated two factor authentication, Google it. The fact is I updated the system, and without any warning I can't update apps anymore. Fail.I am not here to explain all my valid reasons why it is pain for me to go each time through two factor authentication when I need to update apps on my devices. I am here to figure out how to deal with this Apple fail. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thank you. Login into https://appleid.apple.com/ and setting up few things did the job.

Comment: @jksoegaard  Anyway as you advised, login into appleid.apple.com did the job. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Great question, no judgement, +1 I either missed or forgot totally about  this change as it  happened 5 days before WWDC and wasn’t tied to any general release of any OS. Perfectly understandable you would question this change and it might not work now or ever for some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 17, 2020 you can not turn off two-factor authentication and you can not use some features without enabling it. It was optional, highly encouraged and opt-in on iOS 12 and iOS 13.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

> **Can I turn off two-factor authentication after I’ve turned it on?**
> If you already use two-factor authentication, you can no longer turn it off. Certain features in the latest versions of iOS and macOS require this extra level of security, which is designed to protect your information. If you recently updated your account, you can unenroll within two weeks of enrollment. Just open your enrollment confirmation email and click the link to return to your previous security settings. Keep in mind, this makes your account less secure and means that you can't use features that require higher security.

I have not tested the unenrollment in the two week grace period but have no reason to believe it won’t work as described. The services Apple ties to two-factor [(which is easily confused with the previous two-step process)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152)  have been changing outside the iOS major release cycle

***The only thing that’s changed with iOS 14 is Apple removed the opt-in UI since the services themselves are now forcing the upgrade in security.***

You still want to closely manage all the security at this page whenever a device gives you a hassle or unexpected challenge. (This much hasn’t changed in many years)

- https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Once you review your current settings above and make the security page happy, you may have to choose between this model requiring a second factor past your password and managing the prompts, trying it and declining the features or just letting the features that mandate this fail and go unused.  It appears you could also keep using older software with two-step or relying on the security questions and just a password for existing AppleID.