# Can't sign into App Store - wrong password - code on iPad

Tags: macos, apple-id, mac-appstore, two-factor-authentication

The HDD failed in my Late 2012 Mac Mini and I have a new disk installed and have used Internet Recovery to restore Mountain Lion to it.

I'm trying to upgrade but any [attempt through the app store fails because I cannot log in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304037/5472). My password is correct, but it says it is wrong and I hear the notification of approval on my iPad for the code etc.

I cannot turn off two factor authentication as that is [no longer an option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404540/5472).

How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you check that you did not changed keyboard language which may lead to incorrect password entry ?

Comment: Yes, I have typed the password in the terminal and it's typing correctly

Comment: I should also add, that since I get the code on my iPad that would show the password I am typing is correct and just the App Store from OS X ML is not accepting it.

Comment: Did you also checked that the number for the code were correct (number entry may also differ on keyboards) ? Also, did you tried to reboot Mac and iPad ?

Comment: When you say you can not log in, is that due to not being prompted for the pin after your enter the password? Older code and devices have a “Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.” [behavior if they don’t know about TFA - per this FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)

Comment: @bmike thanks very much! No matter what I typed I never found this information and has worked perfectly. Cheers. I'll accept an answer if you want to put one.

Comment: Done! Feel free to edit my answer if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This catches just about everyone - it’s not even something you might think of.

- Type your password and then tack on the PIN code that’s sent.

Older code and devices have a “Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.” [behavior if they don’t know about TFA - per this FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)

It feels wrong, but then it works (hopefully)!